# How to write a simple stored procedure in advantage data architect

Tags: wpf, stored-procedures, advantage-database-server

I am creating a WPF application using Advantage database server. I want to insert some data using stored procedure

Any sample code ?

I tried two input parameter TestID and TestName (both NCHAR)

```
INSERT INTO TestTable(
                    Test_Id,
                    Test_Name)  
         VALUES (
                     @TestID,
                    @TestName);
```

But show error like

> Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = HY000;   NativeError = 5154; 
>   [SAP][Advantage SQL Engine][ASA] Error 5154:  Execution of the stored
>   procedure failed.   Procedure Name: TestInsert. Error 7200:  AQE
>   Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2121;  [SAP][Advantage SQL
>   Engine]Column not found: @TestID -- Location of error in the SQL
>   statement is: 42 (line: 3 column: 5) Error in stored procedure:
>   TestInsert  AdsCommand query execution failed.

I am new in SAP ADS. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use _XXXX notation for input parameters.

ie,

INSERT INTO TestTable( Test_Id, Test_Name)
VALUES ( _@TestID, _@TestName);